# Run SBT in debug mode. "libjdwp:transport.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

Tags: java, scala, debugging, sbt, jdwp

I have system:

debian-sid(8.0)

sbt(0.13.7)

java(tested different versions

1) openjdk 7u75-2.5.4-1

2) openjdk 1.8.0_40-internal-b09

3) oracle jdk 1.8.0_31-b13).

When I try to run app in debug mode

```
sbt -jvm-debug 9999 run
```

I always get an error:

```
Could not find agent library jdwp:transport on the library path, with error: libjdwp:transport.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Any suggestions how to make debugging work?

**UPDATE:**
sbt 0.13.6 works correct. Is it a bug or now it's another way to use debugger in sbt?